# PHP app deployments to Vercel throws a filename conflicting error

Tags: php, vercel

I am trying to deploy my PHP application to Vercel but it throws error below.

> Two or more files have conflicting paths or names. Please make sure path segments and filenames, without their extension, are unique. The path **"api/bootstrap.min.js"** has conflicts with **"api/bootstrap.min.css".**

I was wondering how **bootstrap.min.css** is the same as **bootstrap.min.js**. How do I bypass or solve this error?

Here is my **vercel.json** file.

```
{
  "functions": {
    "api/*.php": {
      "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/api/(.*)",  "dest": "/index.php" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this Vercel Docs. https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions
I found out that  this is because the Vercel treats all of the `api/*` files as a serverless functions, which means both the "api/bootstrap.min.js" and the "api/bootstrap.min.css" will be mapped to the route "/bootstrap".

Using Bootstrap's CDN file solve the issue.